# How can I create a new instance of a window in xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm making a web browsing application on OS X through Xcode, and I was wondering if there was a way to copy a window you already have and make a new one. For example, in my web browser (I haven't gotten to tabs yet), if I wanted to make a new window through something like File>New, how would I do that? I'm very new at Xcode, and I'm sure there's a very simple explanation to this, so any help I could get would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same tab?  Or new window?

You have window based application that works like textedit.

Other way around is create views and keep of loading on selection of tabs. And go to add tabs on runtime.

EDIT:

I would advice you to go with DocumentBased Application

Comment: then you will end up with multiple windows of same application and each window has to be closed.

Comment: alloc, init the nib file and load.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at this. What does that mean?

Comment: Create a document-based application. And everytime you select File->new a new window will open.

Comment: Please just copy and paste the demo into here

Comment: sent... once you get...please remove all code sharing commetns from here.